# How do I do a cascade drop using Knex.js in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm getting this error while trying to delete a table(application) which is referenced by another table (page) .

```
knex.schema.dropTable("application").exec();
```

Error is

```
Possibly unhandled error: cannot drop table application because other objects depend on it
at Connection.parseE (/home/balan/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:526:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/home/balan/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:356:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/balan/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:745:14)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:407:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:403:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just do it with raw sql:

`return knex.raw('DROP TABLE application CASCADE');`

Answer (score 0):

for newcomers; if you don't want to struggle with dropping foreign keys and other constraints, you can do something like that:

```js
const tables = [
    'tags',
    'users',
    'categories',
    'posts',
  ]
exports.down = function(knex) {
 return Promise.all(tables.map(async function (table) {
    try {
      console.log(table, 'down start')
      await knex.raw(`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "${table}" CASCADE`)
      console.log(table, 'down finish')
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.detail)
    }

    return true
  }))
};
```